# Create and send doc (word) file with php

Tags: php, email, ms-word

I have a website that builds simple Word files from details that users insert.
I need to create Word files and send them to email.
I know how to send files with email.
I know how to create Word files with php:

```
    <?php
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");    
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<b>My first document</b>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

For example I accept name of same user, create the Word file just with this name, and send the file to emai.

But after I use this code it just uploads the file. How can I send this to email?

Comment: 1. that is NOT a MS-Word file, that is just a bit of html. 2. there is nothing her that uploads anything. 3. if, as you claim, you know how to send a file per email by means of php, then what is your question here? A word file can be sent as any other file.

Comment: i wont to crate the file from details that users will fill and send the file to email (word file )

Comment: I have the impression you only have a very vague idea oft what you actually want to do. Find out how to create a MS word document. There are examples for that on google. Next, learn how to attach a file to an email message. Last learn how to send an email message by means of php. There are good examples for all that on google.

Comment: i know exactly what i want to do and its very very simple crate word file and send him to email

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't know how to put the generated Word document into a physically file ? That you can then use with your email code that you already have ?

If the above code is an example of how you generate your Word document then you could do something like this.

```
<?PHP

// Get the generated MS Word document data
$ms_word_data = file_get_contents("http://url.to.ms.word.create.file.php");

// Create a temporary file to use as email attachment
$word_temp_file = tmpfile();

// Write your generated MS Word data into the temporary file
fwrite($word_temp_file, $ms_word_data);

// Use the file in your E-Mail code
...
$attachment_file = $word_temp_file;
...


// When you have sent your E-Mail don't forget to do house keeping.
// This will close your filepointer but also delete the temporary
// file your have created.
fclose($word_temp_file);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved through PHPMailer, set it up then add this to attach particular word file to your e-mail
You can get PHPMailer from [here][1]

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'youremail@xyz.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Sub';
$email->Body      = $body;
$email->AddAddress( 'recievers@email.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'wordfile.txt' );
```

and finally

```
return $email->Send();
```

This way you can attach a file to the email.

Comment: i know how send file but i don't know how to crate file and send him for example i have code to send files without PHPmailer

Comment: Then what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: for example i accept name of same user, crate word file just with his name, and send this file to email